# Bash script doesn't work as expected for importing mongodb

Tags: bash, mongodb

```
host=localhost
port=27017
db=cms

for c in `mongo --quiet $host:$port/$db --eval 'db.getCollectionNames()' | sed 's/,/ /g'`
do
    mongoexport --host $host --port $port -d $db -c $c > $c.json
done
```

This gives me a lot of empty files and the file name is as follows: 'users.json' instead of users.json, so the ', I have no idea where they come from. The other thing is I have a file named '['.json and another named ']'.json.

```
mongoexport --uri="mongodb://localhost:27017/" --db records --collection users --out dump.json
```

The above works fine, so I am wondering if it's an issue with the host parameter not being used correctly here.

Comment: Have you check what actually is the result of `mongo --quiet $host:$port/$db --eval 'db.getCollectionNames()' | sed 's/,/ /g'`?

Comment: I am getting: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27107, but it doesn't explain why it's getting the collection names.

Comment: Correct this problem and get real list. And you will be able to answer the question. There are brackets and odd symbols in the answer!

Comment: [
  ... 
  'users'
]

Comment: Jaguar, please anonymize your data and add it in to the question. Let it be the EXACT format.

Comment: @gapsf, this do not help much, the output of `mongosh` is like: `[ 'test1', 'test2', 'test3']`

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ifs-shell-variable https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-for-loop/#For-Loop-Words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the expected output from `mongo --quiet $host:$port/$db --eval 'db.getCollectionNames()'` is something like:

```
[ 'test2', 'log', 'log2' ]
```

So you can use command like:

```
mongosh --quiet $host:$port/$db --eval 'db.getCollectionNames()'|awk -F"[' ,]" 'BEGIN {OFS=" "} { for(i=2;i<NF;i++) if ($i!="") printf "%s\n", $i}'
```

and you will get this result:

```
test2
log
log2
```

which will be OK to export the collections.